# How to adjust metal cabinet round pins?

Tags: cabinets

[image]

How to adjust metal cabinet round pins? Located inside office table cabinet

Comment: Ten to one you just pull them out and place in another hole.

Answer (score 3):

Yank them out, shove them in.

Depending on the fit and age (or how long they've been sitting in the same hole), you might need a pair of pliers to grab them firmly enough, if fingers alone won't budge them.

Comment: Yep.  Just grab 'em with some pliers and they should come out.  But I've found that sometime they may need a bit of twisting to convince them to loosen.